# Specific Network Interface

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, network-interface

What I'd like to do is to force an instance of a browser to use a specific Network Interface.  I've tried: http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/ and was less than successful - besides, I'd like to have an instance of the browser using the other interface.

What I've been doing is firing up a Virtual Box and setting it to use the wireless network interface while the rest of the computer uses the wired network interface.  This works great, except I don't want the overhead of having a VM running.  I'm using this to test firewall settings, etc from an outside connection.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Set up a loopback adapter to your wireless (bridged) then setup a proxy to use that loop back adapter, and set your browser to use that proxy...

Comment: what is the reasoning behind going out one or the other eth? Typically systems have route tables, but not based on software like browsers, but on route to host.

Comment: @Jakub just to get an external IP.  In this instance, I'm tethering my phone - which is outside of the firewall while the rest of the computer is inside the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use a (temp) route in your OS that points to the address of the website. The route would need to have a lower metric than the default gateway.

More info about adding routes to Windows:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/